# Display window again after closing it and setting Focus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window

I have two short questions:

1. How is it possible to reopen a window after closing it.
2. How do I set the focus on the window I open.

It would be nice if someone can help me!

Here is the source code I have so far but I don't know how to go on:

The method calling the WindowController:

```
- (IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender 
{
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

if (NULL == preferences) 
{
    preferences = [[PreferencesController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
}
[preferences showPreferenceWindow];
}
```

This is the Header of PreferencesController:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PreferencesController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate>
- (void)showPreferenceWindow;
@end
```

This is the Main of PreferencesController:

```
 #import "PreferencesController"

 @interface PreferencesController()
 @end

 @implementation PreferencesController

 - (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

 }

 // display the preference window
 - (void)showPreferenceWindow
 {
     [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

     // TODO: window should be focused and if the user press the close button it should be displayed again
 }

 - (void) dealloc
 {
    [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSWindow has this handy method `- (void)setReleasedWhenClosed:(BOOL)releasedWhenClosed`. Set that to NO and you window can open unlimited amounts of times. As to your focus issue: It should already be working to bringing your window to focus.

But since you are using a preference window: may I suggest [DBPrefsWindowController](http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2007-03-11) it is pretty old but it still works today.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The Link you sent me is very helpful :)

I call the method releasedWhenClosed after creating the instance.But nothing new happens. It's still only possible to show the window once. It seems to me that the method doesn't work like I use it.

        preferences = [[IEMacPreferences alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
        [[preferences window] setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];

Comment: Ok solved the problem. Had another mistake in the Interface Builder. Made some stupid things (created my own Files Owner and didn't used the default one) Please don't ask me why ;)

Comment: DBPrefsWindowController for the win!